# dart: enforce strongly typed comparisons

Tags: dart

I've just had to review dart code with a hard to find bug. It looked like this:

```
enum Day{
  Mon,
  Tue,
}

void main(){
  Day today = Day.Mon;

  if(today == 0){
    print("it's Monday");
  }
}
```

The bug is that enums in dart are not integers. The comparison between a Day and any integer will always return false.

However, for a Java developer this probably looks like badly written but valid code. In Java, enums are basically integers. I think it's the same in Go.

Android Studio is aware of the problem and underlines the code in gray. If you hover over the line, it tells you:

> Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types.

The visual markup is very easy to overlook and if you do your code review in something like Github you're probably not seeing this at all.

My question is: Can I somehow enforce type safety in comparisons?
Ideally, I would like to specify a compiler flag that catches this.
For example, the following Rust code does not compile:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", "Hello, world!" == 0);
}
```

> error[E0277]: can't compare `&str` with `{integer}`

In `switch` statements, the compiler enforces type safety, this will not compile:

```
switch(today){
  case 1:
  //...
}
```

Can I get this behaviour for if statements as well?

Comment: I can recommend to add the analyzer to you build/integration/verify server and makes is so some of you analyzer rules are errors. In my projects I am actually made all linter warnings as errors so my commits are marked as "failed" if any warning appear from the analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (or create) your `analysis_options.yaml` file and add the lint for [`unrelated_type_equality_checks`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unrelated_type_equality_checks.html) and to treat it as an error:

```
linter:
  rules:
    - unrelated_type_equality_checks

analyzer:
  errors:
    unrelated_type_equality_checks: error
```

After enabling that, running `dartanalyzer` against your code should generate:

```
error • Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types at foo.dart:9:6 • unrelated_type_equality_checks
```

See the documentation for [Customizing static analysis](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) for more information about configuring `analysis_options.yaml`.  You also can see [Supported Lint Rules](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) for a full list of supported lints.

Comment: awesome, this is really useful. Thanks :D